# Azure Function throws exception for Azure Document Client constructor (works in test harness)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which ultimately executes this line of code:

```
cosmosClient = new DocumentClient(endpoint, key, mode, null);
```

This works perfectly in a large web app we use, and also within a test harness. When I call the code that calls this in an Azure function, it yields the following exception:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.ColdStorageReset. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. zzz.DataLayer: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(System.Uri, System.String, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy, System.Nullable`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyLevel>, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)'.
2018-01-25T22:33:15.436
```

The version of Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.dll is 1.15.1.1 in all locations. I also tried this:

```
cosmosClient = new DocumentClient(endpoint, key, mode);
```

That gave me the same result.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this a compiled Function? How is your `cosmosClient` variable defined and where?

Comment: It's a csx. It's defined at the class level as:         private DocumentClient cosmosClient;

Comment: First, I'm assuming this is a precompiled function on v1 host runtime? What version of NewtonSoft.Json does your project reference?

Comment: NewtonSoft version is 10.0.0.0.

Comment: Yeah, so... you can't do that. :( I'll provide a clearer answer below.

Comment: @DrewMarsh - this is a CSX calling a DLL, all referenced in a bin directory. Everything seems to be in place, or else I think I'd be getting a different error.

Comment: If it's worth anything, it's resolving a bunch of other external references (including my dll) just fine. What I expected this was was that I had version x locally, but then version y in the function bin, and in the difference between the versions the constructor had changed. But my code is calling the constructor with 3 arguments (or four, or five, I've tried them all). I'm baffled.

Comment: Did you upload all the versions of all the dependencies that your custom assembly has?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. I compared the bin directory for the test harness to that and synched them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163913/discussion-between-drew-marsh-and-chris-b-behrens).

Comment: I find a similar issue on the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1679). I test with  default timetrigger template. But I **can't reproduce** it on my side. If it is possible, please have  a try to update the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client version >=1.16.0

Comment: @TomSun I did update to the latest version, and the error message switched to a different message, at least: "Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=2.26.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified." But that version is not referenced anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)? If supplied reproduced project demo code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheesh...this was a real nightmare.

I eventually got past this initial conflict by just updating every dependency in sight. After that, it went away, without me ever understanding fundamentally what the problem was. Then, after another round of updates, it reappeared, this time with the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory library, complaining that it couldn't load a version I wasn't referencing (and in the final tally, I truly wasn't referencing it).

After pulling my hair out trying to figure out where the reference came from, I got desperate and began decompiling the dependent dlls to look at the references. Incredibly, this worked, and I located a dependent dll that was referencing that old version of M.I.C.ActiveDirectory. The overall problem that was occurring here was this:

***My library was referencing a dependent library that was, in turn, referencing the errant version of the problem library. This wasn't apparent when compiling locally because of binding redirects in the app.config.***

Azure Functions don't (natively) support binding redirects, so the redirect has to be implemented manually. I found an implementation of this approach here: https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/how-to-fix-the-assembly-binding-redirect-problem-in-azure-functions/.

Despite what the article indicates, it seems to be fine to call the redirect function every time the function executes. In short, you're adding a function app setting with the binding redirect info, deserializing that in code, and then calling some app domain jiggery-pokery to actually perform the redirect. It works beautifully.

Like the article notes, the only drawback is that you have to update the app setting every time you update the lib, but that's something I can live with for now.